# GCP Vertex AI - what is the return value of gcloud ai endpoints create defined?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Where is the return value of `gcloud ai endpoints create` defined and documented?

I am following GCP coursera Vertex AI model monitoring [Lab: Vertex AI Model Monitoring](https://www.coursera.org/learn/art-science-ml/gradedLti/Ru8lM/lab-vertex-ai-model-monitoring) and the task is asking to get the model endpoint ID from the `gcloud ai endpoints create` command output.

```
# Deploy your model to the endpoint
ENDPOINT_NAME = "churn"
output = !gcloud --quiet beta ai endpoints create --display-name=$ENDPOINT_NAME --format="value(name)"
print("endpoint output: ", output)

ENDPOINT = output[-1]
ENDPOINT_ID = # TODO: Your code goes here
```

[gcloud ai endpoints create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/endpoints/create) documentation shows no information of its return value.

Where is it documented?

Answer (score 0):

The command returns [long running operation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/long-running-operations). There is also documentation of it in [Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.endpoint_service.EndpointServiceClient#google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_services_endpoint_service_EndpointServiceClient_create_endpoint), see Returns section.

See sample curl [request](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/long-running-operations#get-operation) for long-running operation:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
"https://LOCATION-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/OPERATION_NAME"
```

**note**: OPERATION_NAME can be found on your request via  API, mine was [creation of dataset](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/create-dataset-api#create-dataset)

Result:
[image]